# Viewing duplicated rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I know that if I have a DataFrame object in Pandas that I can find out if the row is a duplicate by using the .duplicated() method on the DataFrame. This will return a Series giving True or False depending on whether the row was a duplicate or not. My question is, is it then possible to index the original DataFrame with this object, such that I only return the duplicates (so that I can visually inspect them)?

Comment: Do you mean something like `df[df.duplicated()]`?

Comment: @ajcr, yes, that's what I mean. I was doing something stupid in my code which was preventing this solution from working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [18]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 2, (10, 4)))

In [19]: df
Out[19]: 
   0  1  2  3
0  0  1  1  0
1  0  1  1  1
2  0  1  1  1
3  1  1  0  0
4  0  1  0  1
5  1  0  1  0
6  0  1  0  1
7  1  1  1  0
8  0  1  1  0
9  0  0  0  1

[10 rows x 4 columns]

In [20]: df[df.duplicated()]
Out[20]: 
   0  1  2  3
2  0  1  1  1
6  0  1  0  1
8  0  1  1  0

[3 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks. I was doing something stupid where this type of indexing wasn't working for me (my example was slightly more complicated). But thanks!